# eps file vector quality issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a large vector `.eps` file of 8 logo samples. At 100% zoom, it is crisp and gorgeous, about 4 inches wide and 1.5 inches high on my laptop screen.

I tried `object > rasterize` with `CMYK / 300dpi / type anti-aliasing`, but lost quality and it was pasted into a new art-board at a much smaller size.

I want to save it as `PNG` and `EPS` (yes 2 files) but in a larger size, 500% zoomed for example in the original `EPS` file when exporting to new file, without losing any quality, especially when I downsize it and the fonts should not lose quality at all.

I'm new to Illustrator and it is different from Photoshop function wise. How do I export a PNG version at that size and quality?

Comment: Don't use 'object > rasterize' - it is for when a particular vector element in your Illustrator document must be raster instead, not for general purpose rasterised output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They'll never really be the same quality.** The EPS will scale to the resolution of any device that can render it. The PNG's resolution is fixed to whatever you output.

**The question is: How will the PNG be used?** On screen I hope. Identify the highest resolution device to be targeted and export to that pixel size. If you want ideal rendering on several devices, export several versions

**In Illustrator:**
1. open your EPS
2. scale to the pixel size you need
3. export via "Save for Web"
4. select PNG-24 for maximum quality

You can scale it up further in the SFW dialog by adjusting the "Image size" (don't forget to hit "Apply") without any quality loss. Whatever settings you provide in SFW will be rendered from the vector original.

Comment: It will be my company logo, so web (screen) but desktop not mobile. It has typing in the slogan too, which I don't want to lose quality.

Comment: I exported in a larger quality, but still loses quality if I downsize to 25% (about 200px x 70px), whether png or the original EPS. I downsized in the SFW area, png-24 and it loss quality, especially fonts in slogan. Otherwise it looks vector fine before downsizing.

Comment: So you just export the logo to the pixel size that your web design accommodates. It's not going to be as crisp as that beautiful, zoomed in vector file, but it will be fine if it's been designed to handle the transition to web. You may want to consider a web font for your slogan/tag-line so you can keep the size of your logo file down.

Comment: I'm using Museo Sans 700 for the slogan.

Comment: Which is available as a webfont. I'd probably go that route. Unless you're doing some weird visual effects ... which I wouldn't do in the first place ;)

Comment: It's a graphic logo though, so I'm not sure what is considered "webfont" compared to TTF or OTF

Comment: If you have a webfont license for Museo Sans then you can simply use that font in your CSS and it will display correctly without graphics. You could leave the tag line out of your logo and position it on the page as text styled with Museo. Just a thought.

Comment: @ServerSideX: "I exported in a larger quality, but still loses quality if I downsize to 25%" you should be exporting to EXACTLY the size you need. Do not resize it after export. This will ensure the best possible quality at that pixel size.

Comment: @ServerSideX I second horatio's comment. Read point number 2 in my answer: scale to the **pixel size** you need. That is **to the pixel accuracy**. No scaling in the browser.