# How can I preserve vector file size and quality when exporting to PNG format with Illustrator?

Tags: png, adobe-illustrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eps file vector quality issue](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/eps-file-vector-quality-issue)

I have a large vector .eps file of 8 logo samples. At 100% zoom, it is crisp and gorgeous, about 4 inches wide and 1.5 inches high on my laptop screen. How do I export it at that size and save it in the same quality, but png format at the same size? I'm new to Illustrator and it is different from Photoshop function wise.

Comment: Looks like @ServerSideX had *this* question migrated but also asked separately here.

Comment: Take a screenshot! ;)

Answer (score 5):

- You can't get the "same quality" when comparing vector(ai) to raster (png), Vector is a resolution independent format and will always result in better quality when used. Raster content is constructed of pixels and will always be bound by pixel limitations. What you *can* do is get a good quality raster image from a vector image.

Open the file in Illustrator. 
Choose File > Save For Web
The Save For Web dialog window will open
Click the "Image Size" tab on the right of the window.
Input the dimensions you want.
Under Anti-aliasing, choose "Art Optimized" in most cases
Click Save.

This will save a web-resolution png file of the contents.

Save for web works prety much the same in Illustrator as it does in Photoshop.

Answer (score -1):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6561a.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-61cea

Rasterize a vector object
Select one or more objects.

Do one of the following:

To permanently rasterize the objects, choose Object > Rasterize.

To create the appearance of rasterization without changing the objects’ underlying structure, choose Effect > Rasterize.

Set rasterization options (see Rasterization options), and click OK.

Comment: It lost it's quality when I did that. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you save at 300 dpi?

Comment: Yes I did. Then copied/pasted into new artboard. I also want to save it about 500% zoomed.

Comment: Not only does it get distorted after rasterizing (CMYK / 300 dpi / type anti-aliasing), but it copies and pastes much smaller.

Comment: If the question is closed as off topic and not migrated I suggest you re-post your question there but wait for a moderator to review it.

Comment: What is the size of the new artboard/document?